# I try to write a function to remove all characters in a string expect alphabet. but there is issue in my code

Tags: c, string

I try to  write a function to remove all characters in a string expect alphabet. but there is a mistake in my code as if i enter hello123string23gg3
the output is>> hello2string3gg
so it remove only the first special charter  so i'd like to knew what is the mistake

```
#include<stdio.h>
void remove_all_except_alph(char str[]);
#define size 100
int main()
{
    char s[size];

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets(s);
    remove_all_except_alph(s);
    printf("the string after removing : ");
    puts(s);
    return 0;
}
void remove_all_except_alph(char str[])
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if( !((str[i] >= 65 && str[i] <= 90) || (str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122)) &&  (str[i] != '\0') )
        {
            /* Enter here in case the element is not alphabet and it is not equals to null */
            for(j = i; str[j] != '\0'; ++j)
            {
/* remove this not alphabet character by making each element equals to the value of the next element */
                str[j] = str[j+1];
            }
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use if statement so the condition will be checked and if it true the code inside {}
will be executed so if there is hello123 at 1 the code will be executed to be hello2 and in the next iteration the check will be on 3 so it willn't be printed >> hello2string.... and so on ,,,,, to solve this problem you should use while instead of if

`````````````````````````
#include<stdio.h>
void remove_all_except_alph(char str[]);
#define size 100
int main()
{
    char s[size];

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets(s);
    remove_all_except_alph(s);
    printf("the string after removing : ");
    puts(s);
    return 0;
}
void remove_all_except_alph(char str[])
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        while ( !((str[i] >= 65 && str[i] <= 90) || (str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122)) &&  (str[i] != '\0') )
        {
            /* Enter here in case the element is not alphabet and it is not equals to null */
            for(j = i; str[j] != '\0'; ++j)
            {
/* remove this not alphabet character by making each element equals to the value of the next element */
                str[j] = str[j+1];
            }
        }
    }}
````````````````````````
`````````````````````````

Answer (score 1):

You shouldnt increment i in case of shifting the characters  . You will skip one character if you increment i

```
for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if( !((str[i] >= 65 && str[i] <= 90) || (str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122)) &&  (str[i] != '\0') )
        {
            /* Enter here in case the element is not alphabet and it is not equals to null */
            for(j = i; str[j] != '\0'; ++j)
            {
/* remove this not alphabet character by making each element equals to the value of the next element */
                str[j] = str[j+1];
            }
            i--;
        }
    }}
```